# Is there multiple cursor-like functionality in PyCharm?

Tags: python, editor, sublimetext2, pycharm

I love multiple cursors in Sublime Text and was wondering if there was anything close to equivalent in PyCharm. I haven't been able to find anything other than [Extract Variable](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/extract-variable.html) which kind of does something similar I suppose, but it's definitely not the same thing.

I want to able to press `Ctrl-D` (obviously not that specific combination necessarily) and be able to highlight subsequent occurrences for quick modification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an old thread, but I thought I should mention that, after a mere four years, the [pycharm EAP release](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview+%28EAP%29) includes multiple cursors.

Comment: Link to a blog post on usage for anyone interested: http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2014/03/whats-mining-multiple-cursors-and-selection/

Comment: Now, if I could only import my Sublime Text key bindings, I'd be set.

Comment: `Ctrl+G & Ctrl+Shift+G` is the equivalent of `Cmd+D/Ctrl+D` in Sublime Text.

It has the added advantage that `Ctrl+Shift+G` unselects the last selection, in case you go too far :o)

Comment: @BorisChervenkov Sublime Text can do that as well with `Ctrl-U`. :) Also, `Alt-J` is also mapped to do selections in PyCharm.

Comment: Currently, `ctrl L` skips between occurences `alt J` keeps selecting multiple occurences and `ctrl shift j` unselects

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in PyCharm now! Please, see PyCharm web help: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/multicursor.html

Answer (score 0):

Alt+J will "Select multiple occurrences of a word or a text range﻿". (the same as ctrl+D in sublime text)

From the docs...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html#multiselection

in the section "Select multiple occurrences of a word or a text range﻿".